# MySQL Order By 2 colums (date/frequency)

Tags: mysql

I have a `favorite` table with 4 columns

- `employee_id`
- `product_id`
- `frequency`
- `last_consumed_date`

Now i'm getting the 6 rows with the highest `frequency` for the `employee_id` with a minimal `frequency` of 6.

Example with `employee_id` 1

```
SELECT * FROM `favorites` 
WHERE `employee_id` = 1
AND `frequency` >= 6
ORDER BY `frequency` DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

So far so good!

But now i want to prefer the rows if the `last_consumed_date` is within a month (30 days), So i must do something with:

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= `lastchanged`
```

---

Here is a table example to make it more clear
Table filled:

```
1   5 11  2012-10- 3  
1  13  8  2012-11- 7  
1  18 20  2012- 9-25
1  42 10  2012-11- 3
1  28 15  2012-10-17
1   9  7  2012-10- 8
1  64  9  2012-11- 1
2  24  8  2012- 8-28
2  12  5  2012-10-16
2   5 12  2012-11-11
```

Today is `2012-11- 8`
30 days back is `2012-10- 9`
Table returned after SQL:

```
1  28 15  2012-10-17 <Sorted by 30 days interval and frequency>
1  42 10  2012-11- 3 
1  64  9  2012-11- 1 
1  13  8  2012-11- 7 
1  18 20  2012- 9-25 <Sorted by frequency>
1   5 11  2012-10- 3
```

---

Now the question is, How do i order those 2 things in 1 query?
First an order by the date (with 30 days interval)
and than an order by the frequency of seperated results (inside interval and all others)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohh i think i found my answer by trial-error ^v^

```
SELECT * FROM `favorites` 
WHERE `employee_id` = 1
AND `frequency` >= 6
ORDER BY (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= `lastchanged`) DESC,
    `frequency` DESC 
LIMIT 0,6
```

For those who tried helping! Thank you